# Most natural equivalence between $C^*$-algebras in NCG

Tags: ct.category-theory, oa.operator-algebras, big-picture, noncommutative-geometry

I have listen or read that, in the context of noncommutative geometry,  Morita equivalence is a more natural equivalence for $C^*$-algebras than $*$-isomorphism.

Can someone explain this sentence or know some text that could be helpful?

Does anybody know some comparisons of different $C^*$-algebras categories?

NOTE: I asked this same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722380/most-natural-equivalence-between-c-algebras) en SE last week, it's still unanswered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here I list some facts that may be useful for building your intuition:
**1.** Two *commutative* Morita equivalent $C^*$-algebra are in fact $*$-isomorphic.
**2** If $A$ is $C^*$-algebra and you take $B=M_n(A)$ then $A$ and $B$ are Morita equivalent.
**3** Many invariants for $C^*$-algebras such as $K$-theory or Hochschild or cyclic homology are the same for Morita equivalent $C^*$-algebras.
**4** Two Morita equivalent $C^*$-algebras have the same representation theory so from this point of view they should represent the same "noncommutative space".

Comment: Do you know negative or positive counterparts of points **2,3,4** for $*$-isomorphism?

Comment: In 2. the answer is negative for $*$-isomorphism just because that if $A$ is commutative then $B$ is not (for $n>1$) so $A$ and $B$ can not be isomorphic. Obviously $*$-isomorphic $C^*$-algebras trivially have same invariants (K-theory, Hochschild homology). In point 4. "same representation theory" means that the category of representations are naturally equivalent (objects are representations and morphism are intertwiners between them).

Comment: One more crucial fact: the crossed product $C_0(X) \rtimes_r G$ of the $C^\ast$-algebra of a locally compact Hausdorff space by a free and proper action of a locally compact topological group is, in general, only Morita equivalent to the  $C^\ast$-algebra of the quotient space $C_0(X/G)$. Indeed, $C_0(X) \rtimes_r G$ is necessarily noncommutative the moment $G$ is non-Abelian.

Comment: @truebaran I see. I get the point that Morita equivalence is a good equivalence for NC-spaces, thanks a lot!
Though I would also like to know what do you gain/lose when you consider other equivalences (e.g. Prugovecki)?

Comment: Could you say something about the notion of equivalence in the sense of Prugovecki? I'm not familiar with this notion.